# Setting full background image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a full background image.  Unfortunately, the image isn't even appearing, much less set as full background.  Appreciate the help.

```css
#bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
}
#bg img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg"><img src="img/bg.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
```

Comment: are you sure the path is correct? do you want it in the background so you can have some text over it then <img> is not the right choice

Comment: Yes, I will want to place some text over it.

Comment: I added a code snippet. Is this what you want or do you need something else?

Comment: @DevDiva sent you an email :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need 2 classes

You just need

```
#bg {
  position: absolute; 
  width:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  background-image:url("http://www.yourdomain.com/images/image.jpg");
  background-size:cover;
}

<div id="bg">&nbsp;</div>
```

Have a look at this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/xodomoruxe/edit?css,output) for an example

Comment: If the image isn't a url but in my css folder, then what?

Comment: then you just put url(../css/image.jpg) or you can specify your full domain path

Comment: #bg {
  position: absolute; 
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-image: url("../img/bg.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

Comment: put a non-breaking space in the div  & nbsp ;

Comment: I meant img folder.  :-/   I'm still not seeing an image.

Comment: take away the trailing dots - if its local you probably just need "img/bg.jpg"

Comment: I removed the trailing dots but am not sure what you mean by non-breaking space in the div. Sorry.

Comment: its an ampsersand (& character) folllowed by nbsp and a semi colon

Comment: Thanks, Rachel. Still not working but I imagine it's somewhere else in my code.  I do have a header in there that was placed prior to deciding I wanted a full screen image.

Comment: did you take out the backslash? by the way if you want a full screen image put the code in the body class not the bg class

Comment: I did take out the trailing dots and the backslash.  Changed it to body class and eliminated the div with the bg class. Nada.

Comment: it should look like this if it's local - i just tested it in dreamweaver background-image:url("img/bg.jpg");  and then the rest

Comment: Yes, that's what I have.  There's clearly something else in my code that's preventing the image to appear.  Back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it as a background image you should try the following. I added a code snippet.

```css
#bg {
  position: fixed; 
  background-image: url(http://www.laminart.com/img/product/cad/928_2455_L.jpg);
  width:500px;height:200px;
  padding:0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg">
 text over the picture
  <br><br>
  some addition text
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use following to make it "full"

background-size: cover;